# How to send State in Styling API as a Props for Custom Resuable ReactSelect?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I'm having global ReactSelect with default styling. I need to override just one of the styling's property. Consider the following as the Reusable CustomReactSelect Component.

```
custom-react-select.tsx

export const CustomReactSelect = (props) => {
const defaultStyle = {
 control: (provided, state) => ({
            ...
            backgroundColor: (state.isDisabled) ? '--theia-editorGroupHeader-tabsBackground' : 'var(--theia-input-background)',
            fontSize: 'var(--theia-ui-font-size1)',
            ...
        }),
} 
 ...
return <Select 
              ...
              styles = {...defaultStyle,...props.style}
              ...
              />
}
```

Consider a situation where I just need to override the background of the control Style in a similar fashion.

```
const overrideControlStyle = {
        backgroundColor: (state.isFocused) ? 'red' : 'black'
}
```

I only need the override the backgroundColor, in the end the props that should be sent to the React Select should be as follows,

```
Sent Props...
{
 control: (provided, state) => ({
            ...
            backgroundColor: (state.isFocused) ? 'red' : 'black',
            fontSize: 'var(--theia-ui-font-size1)',
            ...
        }),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. `provided` are the current default styles for the particular component of the select, so your styles need to merge with them.

```js
(provided, state) => ({
  ...provided,
  backgroundColor: 'black',
  ...(state.isFocused && {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }),
  ...(state.isDisabled && {
    backgroundColor: 'var(--theia-editorGroupHeader-tabsBackground)'
  })
})
```

So consider your order of importance with your overrides. whichever conditional you define last will win. If the control is focused, then `backgroundColor` will be red, however `isDisabled` is more important the `isFocused`, so defining it last will use the variable instead.

This might not be exact for your use case, but hopefully will put you on the right path.